# Is there a way to Manipulate data from a Query in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

So my Question is quite simple but because I am not sure if it is even possible.

I only have "MyFirstName" as my ref Data; I don't have the key. 
I don't want to get the key from the query as well, as that Will require me to navigate to the KeyValue data as well. But before getting the value, I need to get the Snapshot value.

In Firebase we have this data

```
MyData{
  KeyValue   {
        Name : MyFirstName
        LastName : MyLastName


  }

  KeyValue2 {
        Name : MyFirstName2
        LastName : MyLastName2


  }
}
```

So In Firebase ref. that is pointing in MyData ,We can do this.

```
ref.OrderByChild("Name").equalsTo("MyFirstName");
```

Now the return would be a Query. Is it Possible to call a put,push, or even setValue from those?

Now since put, push, setvalue is not a member of Query. It is not possible to do this.

```
ref.OrderByChild("Name").equalsTo("MyFirstName").put() <---
```

In basic knowledge, query is just a query. You can't really do anything about it. I just want to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. You'll have to look over the results and update each of them client-side:

```
ref.orderByChild("Name").equalTo("MyFirstName").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot item: snapshot.getChildren()) {
      item.child("Name").getRef().setValue("Aizen");
    }
  }
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
  }
});
```

For more information on queries, see [retrieving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-reading-once). For more on writing data, see [saving data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html).

Comment: Once again, Thanks Frank. Well a Query is just Query. Can't hope too much.

Comment: In general: if the documentation mention the thing that you're trying to do, it's a reasonable assumption that you'll have to think of another way to accomplish your goal.